# Parse log File and store value in object in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a log file which generates following data:

```
2015-07-06 11:07:24 +0522 [ERROR] 
2015-07-06 11:07:29 +0522 [ERROR] index=healthe-int-legacy host=kdatamap.abc.com com.rp.keplar.collector.CollectorException: Could not process additional data, connection lost to data collector service
```

I want to store data in different section like date, time, index value and error related information like 'Could not process additional data, connection lost to data collector service' into database. How to parse so that I can easily store in DB? Please guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to read up the manual on the really powerful [File](http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/ref_c_file.html) and [String](http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/ref_c_string.html) classes.

Consider this rather quick hack:

```
aFile = File.new("/your/file.dat")
    aFile.each_line { |line|
        arr = line.split
        print "date  = " + arr[0] + "\n"
        print "time  = " + arr[1] + "\n"
        print "index = " + arr[4].split('=')[1]
}
```

It does not take into accout that the file might not exist or that the lines might be aligned differently. Have a look at '''regular''' expressions for implementation of a more robust (but unfortunately more difficult to read) matching algorighm.

Basic I/O is described at http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_io.html.